# How to prove this with induction $1 + m + m^2 + m^3 +\dots+ m^{n−1} = \frac{m^{n }− 1}{ m − 1}$ , where $|m| \lt 1$

Tags: logic, induction

I am very confuse where to start and how to do it, I am very new to this kind of problems, would someone be able to guide me ?

Comment: For starters, recognize that you are doing induction "on n." The inductive step is to prove that this holds true for n = k, then prove that it must follow for n = k +1.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Yes thank you! I will try and see how far I can get !

Comment: Small typo: its $\frac{m^n -1}{m-1}$ not $\frac{m^{n -1}}{m-1}$

Comment: And as stated, the result is true for all $m \neq 1$.

Comment: A tip, so you can specify what you've tried and where you're stuck: with induction there are only two parts, the base case and the inductive step, so it's worth saying which troubled you.

Answer (score 0):

The inductive step would be:  $\color{blue}{1+m+\dots+m^{n-1}}+m^n=\color{blue}{\dfrac{m^n-1}{m-1}}+m^n=\dfrac{m^n-1}{m-1}+\dfrac{m^{n+1}-m^n}{m-1}=\dfrac{m^{n+1}-1}{m-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Base step: $n=1$ then $\frac{m^1-1}{m-1}=1$

Induction hypothesis: suppose it is valid for $n = k$.

Inductive step: Let
\begin{align}
(1+m+m^2+\ldots+m^{k-1})+m^{(k-1)+1}&=\frac{m^k-1}{m-1}+m^k\\
&=\frac{m^k-1+m^{k+1}-m^k}{m-1}\\
&=\frac{m^{k+1}-1}{m-1}\\
\end{align}
with this you can already argue